# Render a status code when an error occured

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

When someone accesses my API with something different than an integer value, it should return a 400 Error.

My minimalized index method is:

```
def index
    @returnType = MyType.all

    if params["limit"].present?
        begin
            limit = Integer(limit)
        rescue Exception=>e
            render status: :bad_request
        end
     end

    respond_to do |format|
        format.json
    end
end
```

But, in the exception-case I get a `AbstractController::DoubleRenderError`.

The problem is, Rails doesn't stop the method at `render`, it continued with the `respond_to` part.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `render and return`:

```
if params["limit"].present?
    begin
        limit = Integer(limit)
    rescue Exception=>e
        render status: :bad_request
        return
    end
 end
```

This will render the error and then stop execution of the method.

Comment: NOTE: You should be careful with English `and` and `or` operators. Read this: http://devblog.avdi.org/2014/08/26/how-to-use-rubys-english-andor-operators-without-going-nuts/

Comment: clarified it @Surya, but I question just how confusing that is in this situation.

Comment: Your solution is good, +1, but people who are new to Ruby ecosystem learns more from answers posted on SO. So, `&&` and `and` are widely confused with their applications by beginners and since your answer had it, I couldn't help myself making a note of that for others. :)

Comment: Using `and`, as in the first example, really accomplishes nothing useful. The code runs just as fast, and still returns. The overall style of using `and` that way obfuscates the purpose of the code though, and slows down understanding of what it's doing. Using `and` for flow-control like that is a Perlism, and something that we tend to avoid in Ruby, simply because it impacts readability and maintainability. There is no speedup and no space savings using `and`, so stick `return` on a separate line for clarity.

Comment: I've removed the part with `and`, as the popular opinion seems to be that it's less readable. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: I tried this myself bevor asking this question. Rails won't break at this point - it will render a 400 AND render the json.